# Having a relative path in a module relative to the file calling the module

Tags: python, class, module, path

Let's say I have the current file structure :

- app\modules\module.py
- app\modules\somefile.txt
- app\scripts\script.py
- app\main.py

modules\script.py :

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..\\")
from modules.module import module
[...]
```

main.py :

```
import sys
from modules.module import module
[...]
```

modules\module.py :

```
[...]
fileToRead="somefile.txt"
```

The problem is :

- If my module is imported from main.py, the path to somefile.txt should be `"modules\\somefile.txt"`
- If my module is imported from script.py, the path to somefile.txt should be `"..\\modules\\somefile.txt"`

I don't want to use an absolute path as I want my app folder to be movable.
I thought of a path relative to the root folder, but I don't know if it's a clean solution and I don't want to pollute all my scripts with redondant stuff.

Is there a clean way to deal with this ?

Comment: You have other issues. For example, the `from modules.module import module` in main.py isn't going to work.

Comment: Both main.py and script.py are working correctly (without the reading of the .txt file). Why do you think that it shouldn't work ? Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Does main.py invoke/import script.py, and if so, how?

Comment: It doesn't invoke script.py YET, but I plan to use main.py as program from which I will start several scripts such as this script.py. Is the import going to bring a conflict ?

Comment: Do I understand correctly, you need the absolute path of a module, to access a file relative to that?

Comment: I could get the import to work after setting up your example folder structure and files and executing `main.py`. Executing `script.py` might fix that since it appends to `sys.path`, but then the question becomes how are you going to execute `script.py` from `main.py` since it will have the same issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what all you're doing, but since `somefile.txt` is in the same folder as `module.py`, you could make the path to it relative to the module by using its predefined `__file__` attribute:

```
import os
fileToRead = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "somefile.txt")
```

Comment: This solution is perfect for my case as I only have to modify the modules and not the several script.py I will have. Thank you :)

Comment: That's the point — `module.py` no longer cares how it was invoked as far as locating the data file is concerned.